# How to import PowerShell script in PowerShell start job

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script. We have written some common function and constant variable in other .PS1 file and importing in the main script. Now we are try to implement PowerShell Job to speed up the file upload in batch. Problem is we are not able to import ps file in the start job but before start job I am able to load all functions and variable. How to access these common code inside the job?. In the below code SharePointUrl and UploadFile functions are declared in the constant.ps1 script.

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\..\Shared\Constants.ps1

$csv = import-csv "\\Shared\csvfile.csv"
$RowList = ($csv[$StartRow..$EndRow])
Start-Job -ArgumentList (, $RowList) -ScriptBlock { 
        PARAM ($RowList)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $using:SharePointUrl #This URL should load from Constant.ps1

            $RowList | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
//upload file function call
UploadFile $_.FilePath $_.TargetUrl  # Upload function must get call from Constants.ps1
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to call function and variable from shared PowerShell script inside the Powershell Job.

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\..\Shared\Constants.ps1

$csv = import-csv "\\Shared\csvfile.csv"
$RowList = ($csv[$StartRow..$EndRow])
Start-Job -ArgumentList (, $RowList) -ScriptBlock { 
PARAM ($RowList)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "$using:SharePointUrl" #This URL should load from Constant.ps1

$RowList | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
//upload file function call

$function:UploadFile = "$using:function:UploadFile"
UploadFile $using:$_.FilePath $using:$_.TargetUrl  # Upload function must get call from Constants.ps1

}
}
```